# Is it safe to transfer files to a raid 5 array while it is re-synching?

Tags: windows, sync, raid-5

I have a newly created raid 5 array in windows server 2008 (software in windows disk mamanger) and it is resynching... Is it safe for me to start transfering/copy files to the volume while it is resynching, or should i wait until it is done? what is it resynching anyway when there is no data on it?

Comment: I'd guess that it's building parity data. That said, why RAID 5? You will have a lot of problems with it down the road should you lose a drive...

Comment: It should be redundant enough to lose a drive... I want to store a large amount of data with some redundancy. One drive redundancy with raid 5 seams like a good solution. What kind of problems are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

**Friendly answer:** Yes, you can.

The idea behind any RAID array is that it should act as an usual disk, so if the array is online and available, feel free to use it.  You may experience some performance degradation during the process, but you can overcome this.

**Not so friendly answer:** Understand what the resync process means.

If you are using a RAID-5, besides other benefits, you probably want to be fail-safe.  While the array is resyncing **you are not safe if some of your drives fail** (they are not in sync).  If you are simple setting up your drives, just go ahead and forget they are resyncing, this is normal behavior.  But if you are recovering your RAID array from a crash, you probably want to wait them to finish the resync process.

In any situation, only after the disks finish the resync process you are allowed to say your RAID array is fail-safe.

Comment: This means that you want the resync to finish as soon as possible. For this reason you don't want to start new operations: they are going to delay the resync.

Comment: Not always. When you first set a RAID array it starts a resync process for no data, which means syncing zeros. The parity bit of 0s is 0 (since 0 xor 0 = 0), so it is clearing bits for nothing (but necessary for sanity of the RAID). There isn't anything to lose, but one may notice they are resyncing. You usually want to copy some files to the RAID to finish some setup, and the array will sync again these new files as soon as they are copied (=two syncs). Thus, in some situations, as the initial sync of the RAID, waiting for the resync process to finish is useless.

Comment: Agreed: in this case the array is *newly created*.

Comment: does it mean that each time I put data in the raid 5 array it need to resync for the data to be safe (my nas says 130h for my 6 20TB disks)

Comment: @sliders_alpha Not really. Once the array is sync'ed, all new writes should happen as a big transaction: they do not unsync and only finish a write operation when all necessary data is written (in all disks). This happens to avoid the disk to unsync. In normal situations, a sync should only occur when you're setting up the array or adding/replacing a disk. I'm not sure if copying big files may cause a resync to occur (it seems to be your case). I would say that it doesn't happen, but I may be wrong.